# Keep the app running in foreground

Tags: codenameone

I have an app which shows a checklist and this checklist is useful only if the device does not go to sleep.

Therefore whilst the checklist is shown I want to prevent the device from going to sleep mode.

Does Codename One offer a solution for this - a method like dontSleep(true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Display.getInstance().setScreenSaverEnabled(false);
```